# Change logo based on incoming domain

Tags: php, functions, images, headers

The agency I work for are trying to get a client's logo to change based upon the incoming URL.

Now, we have 4 different URLs, therefore 4 different logos.

Currently, we are using an `if/else` statement, though we keep getting the alt text as opposed to the image. The image source is definitely correct.

```
if(!empty($image)) {
     echo '<h1>WEBSITE_NAME_HERE</h1>';
 } else {
    echo '<img src="'.logoSwap().'" alt="Localised Logo">';
}
```

For the function that has been declared (`logoSwap()`), we are using this code in the functions.php file:

```
<?php
function logoSwap(){
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'WEBSITE_URL_HERE.com': 
        $logo = "WEBSITE_URL_HERE/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/logo-red.png";
    break;
    case 'www.WEBSITE_URL_HERE.com':
        $logo = "WEBSITE_URL_HERE/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/logo-red.png";
    break;
    case 'WEBSITE_URL_HERE.co.uk':
        $logo = "WEBSITE_URL_HERE/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/logo.png";
    break;
    case 'www.WEBSITE_URL_HERE.co.uk':
        $logo = "WEBSITE_URL_HERE/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/logo.png";
    break;
    default:
        $logo = "WEBSITE_URL_HERE/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/logo.png";
    break;
};}
?>
```

The trouble is, only the `alt` tag is feeding through.

[image: Localised Logo Alt Tag]

Is there somewhere specific I should be putting the second PHP script? Am I not calling to the logo correctly?

We are using a Themify theme, so I am not sure whether that will throw a spanner into the works.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a pure PHP problem as you present it. ps: you're missing the `return $logo;` part in the `logoSwap()` function.

Comment: @birgire Okay, I now feel rather silly because the `return $logo;` got the logo to start displaying.

However, I'm still having the problem that it won't change logo based upon the incoming domian.

The `.com` domain is currently set up as a 502 redirect to the `.co.uk` domain - could that be the issue?

Comment: don't be, that kind of code-blindness has and will happen to us all ;-) You mean a  30x redirect (502 usually stands for a bad gateway) ?

Comment: Yes I mean a 301. I did a quick google and must have misread it.

It is using a 301 redirect which is pulling it directly to the `.co.uk` domain, however the logo isn't changing when accessed from the `.com` domain.

Could it simply be the fact that it is coming in via a 301 redirect?

For example, I will type in `mywebsite.com` and I will get redirected to `mywebsite.co.uk`, however it displays the same logo.

Comment: You should create e.g. a pure HTML file where you try to display all the logos, just to make sure they display correctly, before it's all wrapped within a PHP code. I'm afraid I will have to vote to close the question as it's not related to WordPress and therefore off-topic according to the site's rule. Best of luck with the project.

Comment: Would it be off topic in the main Stack Overflow website or the web development sections? If not, would it be possible to get this moved to one of them?

Comment: You could try StackOverflow. I'm afraid I can't change my current vote, but others could vote for a transfer.